# DCdensity() Error - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

When I run the `DCdensity()` function on my data, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (sum(runvar > cutpoint - bw & runvar < cutpoint) == 0 | sum(runvar <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I haven't had this problem with other data, which makes me think there's something about this particular data set that is generating the issue. Here is reproducible code:

```
var <- c(2563174000,
      2256095000,
      1930871000,
      1864063000,
      906536000,
      841016000,
      463844000,
      372356961,
      354815000,
      350592894,
      348630222,
      307796506,
      290368783,
      238275985,
      221192000,
      220601000,
      215029032,
      207318106,
      190921000,
      179007000,
      166989000,
      164345000,
      153026548,
      151993220,
      151274678,
      150578246,
      147045325,
      142770493,
      141066725,
      139734517,
      136362224,
      134755695,
      130338914,
      125605692,
      124778399,
      120896567,
      101406779,
      93756555,
      91139816,
      87003919,
      71630277,
      65446163,
      58752906,
      50478905,
      48435297,
      48347658,
      43022924,
      42508000,
      41243000,
      40609600,
      35926782,
      35599867,
      34769850,
      34546897,
      33433425,
      32515199,
      30753726,
      30687966,
      30233543,
      29769025,
      29372722,
      28993736,
      26931198,
      26641954,
      26187130,
      25630310,
      25257784,
      25103719,
      24454242,
      24334331,
      23760757,
      23449350,
      23119713,
      22301267,
      22246890,
      22070813,
      21790727,
      20886154,
      20353599,
      19965057,
      19641299,
      19592309,
      19571511,
      19533575,
      19035600,
      18844745,
      18781405,
      17337331,
      17311771,
      16981292,
      16035310,
      15969162,
      15381499,
      15083998,
      14957312,
      14853446,
      14579900,
      14336785,
      14148340,
      13969140,
      13909138,
      13859217,
      13525531,
      13288573,
      12850989,
      12807279,
      12693805,
      12234645,
      12035222,
      11913800,
      11854709,
      11466184,
      11154441,
      10884046,
      10883620,
      10872228,
      10840568,
      10575531,
      10365768,
      10199820,
      10100100)

df <- data.frame(var)

DCdensity(df$var, 50000000)
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Any ideas what the problem is? Any ideas what the problem is? Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: In this case it looks like the error is the result of `cutpoint` being too low with respect to the data (`df$var`). There is a binning process that takes place, with the 4th order polynomial being estimated to both the left and right of the cutpoint. With these data there is only a single bin to the left of the cutpoint, and so the polynomial to the left of the cutpoint is linear, with the coefficients being NA. This trickles down to affect the calculation of the bandwith `bw`, which becomes `NaN`. This in turn causes the error you are getting at the `if()` statement.

Comment: A value of 400000000 for `cutpoint` worked for me, for example.